# EF how pass connection string to a different project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, dbcontext

I've a solution with different projects. I'm using EF6 in my 'DALProject' structured with a repository pattern. What I need to do is to make CRUD operations from another project called 'MainProject' that references the one above, but I receive this error: `

```
No connection string named 'MyEntity' could be found in the application config file
```

To resolve this my idea is to pass directly the connection string to the DBContext constructor.
So I copied in an external file the connection string that is in the App.Config of my DALProject, and then I'm going to read this file from the MainProject. This is the connection string:

```
metadata=res://*/My_Model.csdl|res://*/My_Model.ssdl|res://*/My_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=192.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQL2008R2EXP;initial catalog=My_Catalog;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=xxxxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework"
```

When this is done I try to set the DBContext in this way:

```
public class My_Entities : DBContext{
    public My_Entities(string connStr) 
          : base (connStr){}
}
```

But what I got is this error: `

```
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`
```

Any helps?

Comment: Have the connection string as a normal connection string in the calling application. Pass that string when creating the object of your DAL layer

Comment: This should be what I do but doesn't work